# How is it that my postfix server can also be used without authentication?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, authentication

Whenever I send an email via my Postfix server, I see this in the log:

```
   postfix/submission/smtpd: ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
```

That is, I have to authenticate myself.

Whereas, whenever it's done by a spammer who sends an email from my email to my email, from time to time, this is what I see in the log:

```
  postfix/smtpd:  helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=4
```

In the config "main.cf" I have `permit_sasl_authenticated` in each section `NNN_restrictions`.

How can it be that spammers are able to bypass authentication?

update1:

**headers from my MacOS mail app:**

```
Content-Type: ⁨text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"⁩
Mime-Version: ⁨1.0⁩
X-Accept-Language: ⁨en-us⁩
Return-Path: ⁨<spammer123@ah.com>⁩
Content-Transfer-Encoding: ⁨base64⁩
User-Agent: ⁨Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100608 Lightning/1.0b2 Thunderbird/3.1⁩
⁨<D3CAC272.9D74E1A1@ah.com>⁩
Delivered-To: abc@my_email_123.com⁩
Received: ⁨from mail.my_postfix_server123.com by localhost with LMTP id 8S1dAtdQtVzoHwAA0J78UA (envelope-from <spammer123@ah.com>) for <abc@my_email_123.com>; Tue, 16 Apr 2019 03:49:43 +0000⁩
Received: ⁨from ah.com (unknown [ip addr 1]) by mail.my_postfix_server123.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 724471E62C for <abc@my_email_123.com>; Tue, 16 Apr 2019 03:49:29 +0000 (UTC)⁩
Received: ⁨from unknown (ip addr 2) by country_code123.reskind.net with SMTP; Mon, 15 Apr 2019 20:37:59 -0700⁩
```

where `ah.com` is a real domain.

Comment: Please provide your postfix configuration. We can't guess.

Comment: Whenever possible you should [avoid obfuscation](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) and post real information. It doesn't look like this spammer sent from your email address, but from a different address.

Comment: What are the `smtpd_*_restrictions` set to in the configuration(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Since neither ServerFault, Gmail, Hotmail, or any other valid domain that would send email to you and your users has an account on your mail server, those domains can’t authenticate.

So every mail server that needs to accept internet mail needs to accept, without authentication, messages that are destined for the email domain(s) hosted on that server.

Unfortunately that means that undesired senders can also send email to your domain(s).

Comment: `undesired senders can also send email to your domain(s). ` --> not just send, but send from my own email address. How to prevent this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/964958/85791 and similar

Comment: there's no solution that's worked for me there